# Android OpenGL onDrawFrame only called once

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm setting up an OpenGL app for android, and am trying to get a loop running. According to everything I've read, all you need to do is set up the renderer for a GLSurfaceView and then it just calls onDrawFrame repeatedly for the loop. I, however, cannot seem to get it to be called more than once. Here's what I currently have for my setup:

```
    GLSurfaceView view = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    view.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new GestureHandler(view));
    MyRenderer renderer = new MyRenderer();
    view.setRenderer(renderer);
    view.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
    setContentView(view);
```

After putting debug points in MyRenderer's onDrawFrame method, it shows it being called once, and only once at startup. The view is not referenced anywhere else so no settings are overwritten. Am I missing something? I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3

Comment: Did you hook up the `onPause()` and `onResume()`, as described under "Activity life-cyle" in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html)?

Comment: I had not, but after adding it, the problem persisted as that seems to be more for handling closing/reopening the app, not the initial execution. My problem happens starting from the first execution of the app.